# Forward to new page after youtube video finishes?

Tags: youtube-api

I am using youtube's AS3 flash player on my site. Can I make it so that when the video finishes it, it automatically forwards to a specific page? How would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even when using the AS3 player, you can still register javascript handlers; when you load the player just make sure you append

```
enablejsapi=1
```

as a parameter to the URL. Once you've got the javascript handlers registered for the AS3 player, you can then add a javascript listener to the player state change (specifically the ENDED state):

```
function onytplayerStateChange(newState) {
   if (newState===YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
      // do redirect here
   }
}
```

**EDIT**:

Once you have the javascript listener ready, you can then set up an actionscript listener which will call this javascript function on any state change. Something like this, perhaps (untested):

```
// 'loader' below is the youtube actionscript loader object

function onLoaderInit(event:Event):void {
    addChild(loader);
    loader.content.addEventListener("onStateChange", onPlayerStateChange);
}

function onPlayerStateChange(event:Event):void {
    // Event.data contains the event parameter, which is the new player state
// make sure ExternalInterface is imported
    ExternalInterface.call("onytplayerStateChange()", Object(event).data); // calls the javascript function

}
```

Comment: I dont understand how the javascript works. I've added `enablejsapi=1` to my embed code. Then I added that function to my javascripts (with a simple alert popup) and nothing happened. Is there something else I need to do besides adding these 2 small pieces of text?

Comment: Yes ... you have to bind to this listener function. There are several different ways to do that, depending on the method you used to set up the embed. Are you coding the action script yourself? If so, you'll have an init function somewhere in which you can bind the stateChange event to the javascript function above. See my edit for a quick and dirty (but warning ... untested) example.